# how to make team members section using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Since I'm new to bootstrap, I've assignment to make a section of team members. Everything I've completed but only the **Blue Area** where the information is displayed about each member separately, I could not resolve. So please tell me how to resolve it. Thanks
[Team Members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPce.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <style>
    .row{ background-color: brown; }
    .col-md-3 img{ height:325px; width: 100%; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;}

    .text-block {
        height: 100px;
        width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 15px;
    background-color: #30374d;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    clip-path: polygon(-36% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 1%);
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.name{ padding-top: 25px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/1065-IMG_2529.jpg"> 
                  <div class="text-block text-right">
                     <h4 class="name">NAME</h4>
                        <p>Join Date</p>
                  </div>
             </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/1065-IMG_2529.jpg"> 
                  <div class="text-block text-right">
                     <h4 class="name">NAME</h4>
                        <p>Join Date</p>
                  </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/1065-IMG_2529.jpg"> 
                   <div class="text-block text-right">
                     <h4 class="name">NAME</h4>
                        <p>Join Date</p>
                  </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/1065-IMG_2529.jpg"> 
                   <div class="text-block text-right">
                     <h4 class="name">NAME</h4>
                        <p>Join Date</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="image1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
   
      <img src="image2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="image3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
<img src="image4.png">
    </div>

   
    
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, using bootstrap3, you can try the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```